# newrelic for laravel to track routes response time

Tags: php, laravel, newrelic

I am trying to add newrelic to my [laravel site](https://github.com/ypapax/newrelic_laravel_example_new/blob/master/commands.sh#L17). I found this [repo](https://github.com/In-Touch/laravel-newrelic#basic-use). But couldn't use it properly.

Where should I put this code?

```
App::after( function() {
    Newrelic::setAppName( 'MyApp' );
} );
```

Or maybe other ways to add routes response time to newrelic...

Comment: In the service provider of the package which you published?

Answer (score 2):

`App::after` does not exists anymore.

You can register a middleware that is executed after the request to do what you need:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class AfterMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);

        Newrelic::setAppName( 'MyApp' );

        return $response;
    }
}
```

and register it as usually in app/Http/Kernel.php:

```php
 protected $middleware = [
        ...,
        \App\Http\Middleware\AfterMiddleware::class
    ];
```

Comment: Did you get this to work Maxim? I do not get the downvote. Leave a comment if you got it to work and I'll vote.